# How would i get the rest of a string within a longer string by specifying the end point

Tags: php, html, regex, meta-tags, meta

Alright I'm a bit stuck here.

Here is the code with explanation below:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
if (strpos($html, "<meta name='description") !== false) {
  // found
  //get rest of it and return string.
} else {
  // not found
  //return FALSE;
}
```

I am getting the full HTML of a page to check if a meta description is set. The content is not always the same so I only retrieve the initial part: "

What i want to know is how i would get the rest of it i.e. "content="$whatevercontent>"".

Any advice is much appreciated here.

Thanks!

Comment: just use an HTML parser

Comment: The problem with your approach is that it's susceptible to whitespace differences, case differences  and changes in the order of the attributes. If you want the `content` attribute of the `meta` tag your best option is to use the [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class and extract it from there.

Comment: PHP already has a built-in string extractor for that: [`get_meta_tags()`](http://php.net/get_meta_tags). And yes, firing up libxml for such tasks is silly.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, so realised that what I was doing was pretty terrible as there is already a [get_meta_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) function in PHP! That is what I'm now using.